# Composing a dynamic Rails where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following logic in a controller action logic determines a single attribute to be looked up via the variable `zone`  (one of `delivery`, `pickup`, `zone_1`, `zone_2`, `zone_3`, `zone_4`, `zone_5`, `zone_6` ...)

```
  if !zone_user.nil? && deliver?
    zone = "zone_" + zone_user.sequence
  elsif zone_user.nil? && deliver?
    zone = 'delivery'
  else
    zone = 'pickup'
  end
```

However the query cannot be stated as such

```
day_slot = Day_slot.order(id: :asc).
   where(['day_id IN (?) AND slot_id IN (?) AND zone = ?', @day, @slots, true]).all
```

since `column "zone" does not exist`.

How should this query be composed?

Comment: if `zone` is a variable that contains the column you want to query, why not just use string interpolation in your query? `where(["day_id IN ... AND #{zone} = ?" ...`

Comment: [argh.  slipping on the banana peel I had cast].  with **double** quotes.  the clause with cingle quotes had returned `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{")`

Comment: In which case - I'll add it as a full answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use string interpolation in your where query. You just need to switch to double quotes:

```
day_slot = Day_slot.order(id: :asc).
   where(["day_id IN (?) AND slot_id IN (?) AND #{zone} = ?", @day, @slots, true]).all
```